# Nullable field on a One-to-many relationship EFcore C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, swagger

I have this models

(pet) Mascota.cs

```
namespace BE_CRUDMascotas.Models
{
    public class Mascota
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Raza { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public float Peso { get; set; }
        public int DueñoId { get; set; }

        public Dueño Dueño { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(owner) Dueño.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace BE_CRUDMascotas.Models
{
    public class Dueño
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Cedula { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }


        public virtual List<Mascota> Mascotas { get; set; } = null!;


    }
}
```

and this is the post method in DueñoController.cs to create an owner

```
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(Dueño dueño)
        {
            try
            {
                dueño.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Dueños.Add(dueño);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = dueño.Id }, dueño);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
       }
```

the reasoning is that an owner has many pets, but a pet just one owner.

The thing is that you need to create an owner first to be able to create a pet that can be linked to an owner, when I run the swagger I try to leave that "List Mascotas" field empty, but it says it is required, even when I use "= null!" on the field, I've also try to use "[BindNever]" but it doesnt work.

Is it possible to let that field empty or I need to delete the field?

I'm using net 6

Comment: (1) A code in english would be far better (2) `public virtual List<Mascota>? Mascotas { get; set; };` will allow null list or you can also create one empty (3) If I may suggest, read a technical book to get ride of this kind trouble, like `C# 10 and .NET 6 - Modern Cross-Platform Development` (great at least for building strong and solid basic base for .NET), it has been a life saver for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let that field empty, try to add `?`:

```
public virtual List<Mascota>? Mascotas { get; set; }
```

**Or** to eliminate the warnings from nullable reference types, remove the following line from the BE_CRUDMascotas.csproj file:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

You can have a look at [Build the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

Comment: Hi @Javi Luna , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: hi, yes this worked. It was as simple as that.  Is this  the way that relationships are handle usually? When you use sotred procedures to interact with de DB there is no need to have a list in your A class model that stores B class model instances when both are related.
I don't know to much about EFcore as I'm learning by myself, but the most obvious use that I see for this is that you can easily instance B whe you are creating A

Comment: Hi @Javi Luna, yes , no need to sore the Mascota list in the Dueño table in DB, a collection navigation on the principal entity referencing the dependent entities ,like:Dueño.Mascotas is ok  , and the error is about compiler generates several warnings about how null values are handled. You can have a look at [One-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many) and [EF Core One To Many Relationship](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration) to know more.

Comment: And you can use the [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) method to specify related data to be included in query results.

Answer (score 2):

First change the declaration to have an implementation by default, this enables the serializers to call `.Add()` for each item in the array:

```
public virtual List<Mascota> Mascotas { get; set; } = new HashSet<Mascota>();
```

I know you are trying not to add the Pets, this is usually enough to allow the validators to do their thing.

Does it fail from Postman or just in the swagger UI?

Note that you can include the child Pet records in the initial Post too, it doesn't have to be separate posts to the other controller.